# Spring OAuth2 "Full authentication is required to access this resource"

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to use Spring OAuth2 for my rest app. 
But looks like I made a mistake and I can find where I did it. 
The flow should be:
1. get token from /oauth/token with username and password
2. make request to /security with provided token

MethodSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private SecurityConfiguration securityConfig;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }
}
```

OAuth2ServerConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfig {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "nessnity";

    @Configuration
    @Order(10)
    protected static class UiResourceConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/security")
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/security").access("hasRole('USER')");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/security/")
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/security").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
      }

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Autowired
        private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient("my-client")
                    .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                    .scopes("read")
                    .secret("password")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60);
        }

        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new InMemoryTokenStore();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints
                    .tokenStore(tokenStore)
                    .userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
            oauthServer.realm("sparklr2/client");
        }

    }

    protected static class Stuff {

        @Autowired
        private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Bean
        public ApprovalStore approvalStore() throws Exception {
            TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
            store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
            return store;
        }

        @Bean
        @Lazy
        @Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
        public SparklrUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler() throws Exception {
            SparklrUserApprovalHandler handler = new SparklrUserApprovalHandler();
            handler.setApprovalStore(approvalStore());
            handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
            handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
            handler.setUseApprovalStore(true);
            return handler;
        }
    }

}
```

SecurityConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("root")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/oauth/uncache_approvals", "/oauth/cache_approvals");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("USER");
    }
}
```

Problem: when I tried to get token

```
curl --user root:password --data "grant_type=client_credentials" http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
```

I got message:

> {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Bad client
>   credentials"}

The second question is how to pass username/password in the url params like /oauth/token?username=root&password=password ?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I decided to start from scratch and use xml configuration.

The following configuration works perfect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd

        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">


    <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
          authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
        <anonymous enabled="false"/>
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
    </http>

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    </bean>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
                            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService"/>
    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientDetails" class="com.nessnity.api.security.OAuthClienDetailsService">
        <property name="id" value="testuser"/>
        <property name="secretKey" value="secret" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="springsec/client"/>
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler"/>

    <oauth:authorization-server
            client-details-service-ref="clientDetails"
            token-services-ref="tokenServices">
        <oauth:authorization-code/>
        <oauth:implicit/>
        <oauth:refresh-token/>
        <oauth:client-credentials/>
        <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="userAuthenticationManager"/>
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <authentication-manager id="userAuthenticationManager"
                            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider ref="customUserAuthenticationProvider">
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="customUserAuthenticationProvider"
          class="com.nessnity.api.security.OAuthUserAuthenticationProvider">
    </bean>

    <bean id="tokenServices"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true"/>
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="900000000"/>
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tokenStore"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore"/>

    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    </bean>

    <http pattern="/resources/**" create-session="never"
          entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" method="GET"/>
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
    </http>

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
                           resource-id="springsec" token-services-ref="tokenServices"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: I don't see any configuration for `/oauth/token` anywhere. And *don't* ever pass sensitive information like usernames and passwords in parameters; they get saved in histories and the like.

Comment: @chrylis I expect that it will be available by default.. from the spring oauth documentation: "TokenEndpoint is used to service requests for access tokens. Default URL: /oauth/token.". am i wrong?

Comment: Were you trying to use Spring Security to secure that endpoint? If not, your intentions for how you were going to get the user's credentials into the endpoint processor aren't clear.

Comment: @chrylis yes, this is not clear for me. should i setup this endpoint manually or it is available by default? it was the second question. i reviewed spring oauth examples sparkl/tonr but i still can't understand how it works. especially flow with tokens.

Answer (score 6):

I have faced similar for me it worked after doing the following change

In your *AuthorizationServerConfiguration* class replace

```
        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
            oauthServer.realm("sparklr2/client");
        }
```

with the below code

```
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        //oauthServer.realm("sparklr2/client");
        oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }
```

and request should like

> /oauth/token?grant_type=password&scope=read+write&client_id=yourclientId&client_secret=secret&username=userName&password=pwd

Answer (score 0):

In your access token request you are using client credentials grant type. OAuth spec says that in case of client_credentials grant type you need to provide base64 encoded `client_id:client_secret` as  Basic Authorization header.
For example if your client_id is `google` and client_secret is `x23r-ss56-rfg8-6yt6`, then you need to add these string as `google:x23r-ss56-rfg8-6yt6`, encode it using Base64 encoder and make request as

```html
curl --header "Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded_string>" --data "grant_type=client_credentials" http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
```